# CompletableObserver No Suitable Method Found

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

Still a little new to RxJava and trying to implement a method that returns a Completable:

Here is the retrofit class:

```
@GET
Completable fetchSomething(@Url String url);
```

And here is where I am calling that method:

```
myRetrofit.fetchSomething(url)
    .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }
    });
}
```

Seems pretty straightforward, but the body of the CompletableObserver won't compile. I get this error:

> error: no suitable method found for subscribe(anonymous CompletableObserver)
>  
>   method Completable.subscribe(Action0) is not
>   applicable
> (argument mismatch; anonymous CompletableObserver cannot
>   be converted to Action0)
>  method
>   Completable.subscribe(CompletableSubscriber) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; anonymous CompletableObserver cannot be
>   converted to CompletableSubscriber)
> method
>   Completable.subscribe(Subscriber) is not applicable
> (cannot
>   infer type-variable(s) T
> (argument mismatch; anonymous
>   CompletableObserver cannot be converted to Subscriber T ))
> where T is
>   a type-variable:
> T extends Object declared in method
>   T subscribe(Subscriber T)

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: try subscribeWith instead of just subscribe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have both RxJava1 and RxJava2 in your project. Once in API you use `Completable` from RxJava1 in the code you are trying to use `subscribe(CompletableObserver)` method which is from RxJava2